# Текст собрался в кучу на одной строке

Tags: css

Я так и не понял как это исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
    .row {
      letter-spacing: -0.31em;
      *letter-spacing: normal;
      *word-spacing: -0.43em;
      text-rendering: optimizespeed;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="span-4 widget welcome-feature">
        <i class="livicon" data-n="tablet" data-c="#C1C1C1" data-op="1" data-s="68" data-hc="false"></i>
           <div class="widget-content">
            <div class="title">
             <h4>Retina Ready</h4>
           </div>
    <p>Cum socis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur maximus ridiculus mus.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Этот вопрос решен, но теперь новая проблема. Когда я убрал эти параметры блоки перестали быть в одну линию.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском. Чтобы на ваш вопрос можно было ответить, выложите код страницы, который рендерится в такой текст. Пока что угадать невозможно.

Comment: Наверное, еще нужна css, в которой определены стили.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да уже нашел всё, вот так всегда, создашь вопрос на стеке и всё сразу находится :(

Comment: так это же хорошо )) Дайте ссылку на ответ, я отмечу этот как дубликат. Будет больше шансов найти у будущих читателей.

Comment: А судя по CSS у вас word-spacing отрицательный, потому и сбились.

Comment: Про новую проблему лучше задать новый вопрос. Там сразу скриншот новой проблемы и код, который ее воспроизводит. Кстати, там есть кнопочка с `<>` специально чтобы вставлять код на HTML/CSS/JS. Я тут поправил, посмотрите )